# Singleton COM object required

Tags: .net, com, clr

Is it possible to create the single instance of COM object, and be sure all subsequent calls from any client will be made to this single instance only?

Comment: How unique does it need to be? Unique within a process? Unique across processes within a session? Unique even among processes running as different users?

Comment: @BrendanMcK, "unique within all processes under the same user session" is enough

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that you will have to to make your COM object run Out-of-process (exposed by an EXE).

Do you really need the very same COM object used everywhere? Or do just want to control the same underlying resources from a single control point?

COM doesn't support the Singleton pattern directly, but it doesn't stricktly forbid it either. It's just that there is no registry setting that says "always serve the same object". In fact, the standard COM instantiation mechanism *requires* that a truly new object be returned each time you call it (this mechanism is what `new` operators and `CreateInstance()` use internally) . That means that to make a proper COM singleton, you cannot let your clients create it themselves. This can all be done, but it's tricky and rarely necessary.

Your best bet - funny enough - is to NOT have a COM Singleton at all. Let the client create as many different objects as it wants. Instead of a single COM object, allow multiple COM objects but make those objects "shims" which communicate with a single - internal - object implementation. Don't expose the internal singleton implementation directly as a COM object at all. You will avoid a lot of headaches.

Comment: And in your case, you have an extra problem in that it's hard to guarantee that COM will use the same process to service every request for the object. If you absolutely have to guarantee that under no circumstances there can be more than one object, you'll have to take extra steps. I think that registering your server under Component Services should do the trick, but I've gotten rusty; I would have to look it up to make sure.

Comment: A use case for this is when your COM server has a client that creates new instances but does not release them, and leaks memory, on a regular basis and you do not own the client code.